# How to scrape review data present in Read more in Flipkart reviews

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape Flipkart to extract reviews for a product using request and beautifulsoup package.how can take out data present in Read more click event present in those review.

Comment: you have to use selenium,geckodriver,bs4 to scrape the sites like Flipkart.

Comment: Can't we do without using selenium?..with only beautiful soup package

Comment: Nope, can you check the answer and let me know if you're okay with it. because it's working code. if helpful, please accept the answer.

Comment: Actually I have taken out all the details required .. except reviews that was pending due to read more issue..let me try

Comment: You can actually map the urls with this script as a function or tweak it as you want. Sure Thank you and all the best :-)

Comment: Can you provide us the url of an example?

Comment: https://www.flipkart.com/poco-f1-graphite-black-64-gb/product-reviews/itmf8fyjyssnt25c?page=1&pid=MOBF85V7A6PXETAX ..I have taken out all the necessary details..except reviews ..due to read more thing.. i have used beautifulsoup and requests package

Answer (score 2):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodedata

def remove_non_ascii_1(text):

    return ''.join([i if ord(i) < 128 else ' ' for i in text])

with closing(Firefox()) as browser:
    site = "https://www.flipkart.com/asus-zenfone-2-laser-ze550kl-black-16-gb/product-reviews/itme9j58yzyzqzgc?pid=MOBE9J587QGMXBB7"
    browser.get(site)

    file = open("review.txt", "w")

    for count in range(1, 10):
        nav_btns = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_33m_Yg')

        button = ""

        for btn in nav_btns:
            number = int(btn.text)
            if(number==count):
                button = btn
                break

        button.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_2xg6Ul")))

        read_more_btns = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_1EPkIx')


        for rm in read_more_btns:
            browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", rm)
            browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, -150);")
            rm.click()

        page_source = browser.page_source

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "lxml")
        ans = soup.find_all("div", class_="_3DCdKt")


        for tag in ans:
            title = unicode(tag.find("p", class_="_2xg6Ul").string).replace(u"\u2018", "'").replace(u"\u2019", "'")
            title = remove_non_ascii_1(title)
            title.encode('ascii','ignore')
            content = tag.find("div", class_="qwjRop").div.prettify().replace(u"\u2018", "'").replace(u"\u2019", "'")
            content = remove_non_ascii_1(content)
            content.encode('ascii','ignore')
            content = content[15:-7]

            votes = tag.find_all("span", class_="_1_BQL8")
            upvotes = int(votes[0].string)
            downvotes = int(votes[1].string)

            file.write("Review Title : %s\n\n" % title )
            file.write("Upvotes : " + str(upvotes) + "\n\nDownvotes : " + str(downvotes) + "\n\n")
            file.write("Review Content :\n%s\n\n\n\n" % content )

    file.close()
```

Usage:

1. Install the requirements by running pip install bs4 selenium.
2. Add geckodriver to the PATH. Follow these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path).
3. Put the link of the product in site variable inside the script.
4. Run the script by running python scrape.py.
5. Reviews will be saved in the file review.txt.

Comment: Could you explain the functionality of `rm.click()?` I have inspected the webpage and found that the **READ MORE** is in a span tag and there is no link associated with it. How are you pointing your cursor exactly at that **READ MORE** word?

Answer (score 0):

Had some issues using @CSMaverick code while accessing the READ MORE link. Modified the code as per my requirement.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_source_code(browser):
    rm_btns = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_1BWGvX')
    for rm_btn in rm_btns:
        rm_btn.click()
    return browser.page_source


def collect_reviews_attributes(html):
    soup_obj = bs(html, "html.parser")
    text_tag_divs = soup_obj.find_all('div', attrs={"class", "t-ZTKy"})
    heading_tag_divs = soup_obj.find_all('p', attrs={"class", "_2-N8zT"})
    rating_tag_divs = soup_obj.find_all('div', attrs={"class", "_3LWZlK _1BLPMq"})
    text_tags = [tag.text for tag in text_tag_divs]
    heading_tags = [tag.text for tag in heading_tag_divs]
    rating_tags = [tag.text for tag in rating_tag_divs]
    return list(zip(heading_tags, text_tags, rating_tags))
    
collector_list = []    
    

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"path to\geckodriver.exe")
url = "https://www.flipkart.com/samsung-253-l-frost-free-double-door-3-star-convertible-refrigerator/product-reviews/itmf75fa1554bad3?pid=RFRFNDEEJ28SNQPG&lid=LSTRFRFNDEEJ28SNQPGEJ3YHJ&sortOrder=MOST_HELPFUL&certifiedBuyer=false&aid=overall"
num_pages = 3 # get from the url dynamically or else give large number and try hitting until u get exception

browser.get(url) # open the url in the browser
for _ in range(num_pages):
    page_source_code = get_source_code(browser)
    collector_list.extend(collect_reviews_attributes(page_source_code))
    next_page = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_1LKTO3')[-1] # previous and next are under same class. Access last element
    next_page.click()
```